# Why  winform using external dll(VC) and ocx(VC) control can only import one?

Tags: c#

We have a .net framework application with a vc dll and a vc ocx, and now if we only import one dll it is ok, but when we import both, it will pop up a messagebox saying: Debug Assertion Failed!

I studied the child module of our application that imports the vc dll, and I found after the framework import vc ocx and initialize, then the function LoadLibrary in our module importing the vc dll would return 0, that means memory limited or it's being called improperly.

I use getlasterror() the error code is 1114.

So I am very frustrated, hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a compatibility issue. Are you loading third party controls or inhouse controls?

Error code 1114 means that the DLL initialization failed (IIRC, the DllMain function fails).

Comment: Yes, DllMain() returned FALSE.  Find out why with a debugger.

Comment: we use a third party controls(vc ocx) imported by a C# dll, just add a item in the toolbox and drag to the form, while the vc dll we used is imported using a vc-multidoc-dll-2-C#-form adapter dll(vc). in our application framework we use dllimport() to use a function in the adapter dll, it just create a control and add to the form container, just like createwnd(...pane.tohandle(), vc-dll-wnd-class-name, wndname).

Comment: so u see our project is not designed properly for we cooperate with a lot of other companies. now the situation is first ocx then the adpater dll cannot loadlibrary the vc dll; if first vc dll then the ocx will give the messagebox: debug assertion failed.
our environment is not allowed me to debug them together because of the third party license just giving us user authority not develop. so is there any other method or common solution to the compatibility issue? thank u